# In Objective-C Can I Treat a Property As An Array?

Tags: objective-c, c, pointers, properties

In good ole C I can do this:

```
int array[5];
int *iptr = array;
```

I have an Obj-C class with an ivar:

```
    float   *m_quad;
```

exposed via a synthesized @propery:

```
@property (nonatomic) float *quad;
```

Is there anyway to do this:

```
float f = myClass.quad[2];
```

Assuming of course I have malloc'd and set values for m_quad?

Thanks,
Doug

Comment: Have you tried it? Maybe (myClass.quad)[2] will work.

Comment: Did you try it at all? I can't think of an obvious reason for you not being able to declare c arrays as properties, or access them using c syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should work of the bat. I have an ivar and property

```
float diffuseColor_[4];
@property (readonly, nonatomic) float* diffuseColor;
```

The property is not synthesized, but using a simple accessor I can write

```
- (float*) diffuseColor
{
    return diffuseColor_;
}


object.diffuseColor[3] = 1;
```